# Blank screen on boot

Tags: boot, blank-screen

Got a laptop to fix. For some reason after a shutdown the hard-drive corrupted. I assumed it was a hard drive problem, so tried with another hard-drive and that seemed to work.

Everything was going fine, I install Avast, reboot and get a bluescreen with 
"Stop : 0x000000a5 ..."

After a quick google it showed me that it could've been a bad memory seating, so I took the memory out and replaced it.

Rebooted again and all I got was a blank screen. Tried the powercycle thing (Hold powerbutton for 1min+ without any power/battery connected), switched memory out with a (known) working memory. Still nothing. Any thoughts?

Also tried connecting to an external monitor (tv screen) but don't know if it would show if it's still in BIOS/Bluescreen(the 0x000000a5 thingie) so not sure if it's screenrelated. Any ideas on how to check that for sure?

Laptop is an Asus X55a.

EDIT:
No beeping sounds either, the harddrive is however spinning.

Comment: "0x00000a5 thingy" is not enough information. "0x00000a5" isn't a valid error code for one. :) What was the actual bugcheck code reported?

Comment: I explained it before in the post. Bluescreen with "Stop : 0x000000a5 ..." If you google that you get a valid errorcode. It even has a microsoft support page : http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/831691

"0x00000a5 thingie" was a reference to the bluescreen.

Comment: "0x00000a5" is NOT a valid hex code, it's only 7 digits after the 0x, it should be 8 (for a 32-bit code).

Comment: Apparently I missed a zero. My apologies.

Comment: That's what I was trying to get you to clarify. If you had missed a zero at the end it's be much different then one missed in the middle, or if the missed digits was something completely different. :)

Comment: [Looks like you have a BIOS problem](http://errlookup.azurewebsites.net/?err=0x000000a5) (or something messing up the ACPI anyway).  Have you tired updating the BIOS to the latest revision offered by Asus? How about other drivers, are they all up-to-date?

Comment: How can I update the bios if I can't even reach it? The screen is black. The faultcode happened, I reseated the memory as shown in other threads describing this faultcode. and after reseating the screen never showed anything anymore.

Comment: The error code isn't the main problem anymore, as I explained in the post..

Comment: So you're a the point now where it won't boot at all?  Try taking the battery out and run just on AC.  If you remove all the RAM does it behave the same way?

Comment: I've been running on AC for the last hour. It does behave the same way without RAM, so no beeping sounds. Also tried with confirmed working RAM. No changes. Well, I don't know if it boots or just doesn't show me it boots..